# Node.js and mongoose - prevent salt and password to return to client

Tags: node.js, security, mongoose

I have a node.js app with mongoose. my problem is that when returning entities with populated user, the user data includes secure data like salt, tokens and password. I used the following method to prevent private data from going back to client:

```js
User.methods.toJSON = function() { // Do not change to lambda expression
 const SERVER_ONLY_PROPERTIES = ['tokens', 'salt', 'password'];
 var user = this.toObject();
 
 SERVER_ONLY_PROPERTIES.forEach(propKey => {delete user[propKey]});
 return user;
}
```

Everything worked great, until I used the lean() function in my code. 
when using lean the toJson method isn't being called and the private data returns to client. what are my options?

Comment: Don't use `lean()` then. And use [select](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) when finding  to only select the fields you want.

Comment: Other developers might use the lean method. I don't think they will remmber this in a year. its to risky

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking out the stuff that you don't want to return, you should instead have a process that builds a new object to return that explicitly includes only the necessary pieces of data. That's the best practice as far as security, if I'm not mistaken.